# What are some alternatives to using the currently-unavailable FreeText search in SQL Azure besides Lucene.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, azure, lucene

We are in the process of planning a migration to Azure.  The current application uses SQL Server FreeText search.  However, as I understand it, Azure does not yet support this.  I have read about how to [Lucene.net working with Azure](http://chriskirby.net/getting-full-text-search-up-and-running-in-azure/) to get better search functionality, however, this requires dumping part of the data into blob storage.

In our case, use a [data mart](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/data-mart) with full text search.

In hopes of not rewriting our whole data access portion, we can move the data mart to another db type - NoSQL, or other suggested ones.

What are some good alternatives besides Lucene.net that will run on the Azure cloud that will give us the same search features as free text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you run a VM on Azure with [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/). Elasticsearch internally still uses Lucene but has created a nicer API to work against and better API then Lucene (IMHO). + it uses Json as data transport.

This solution will require you to 'index' your data from SQL to your Elasticsearch index to prepare it for free text searching but will result in more influence in the searching process thus better results.